# Did I fudge up or is my paint just too light?

Tags: walls, paint

I am needing to do touch-ups around the house and I grabbed a sample off the wall since our handyman fudged up some of the paint anyways, took it down to home depot and the lady made me a quart, she did the little dot on the top and it looks pretty damn identical, I took it home and started my touch ups but noticed it was a fair bit lighter than what she dabbed on the top, now it clicked about 20 mins later I forgot to stir it (durr moment, but I figured since I just had it made up it'd be fine).

If I gave it a nice drill mixing is it possible that it'll get darker?

Comment: The shaker in the paint mix machine should have given it a better stir than you'll ever manage manually. Those things are *fierce.*

Comment: Answers are good. The solution is to paint corner to corner.

Comment: is the paint dry? wet paint can look an entirely different colour once its dried

Comment: It's not just the color, it's the sheen.  I still hate Glidden for stopping the manufacture of their high hiding white.

Comment: @SteveWellens Hiding is the job of primer.  I buy $300/gal paint and I get print-through on 1 coat.  I don't get mad, I mix their white and gray primers to get a lightness which matches the final coat. Then I use 2 final coats.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  "High Hiding" was the name of the paint.

Comment: @Steve yeah, the consumer-facing house paint space is chock full of bad ideas, like combination paint-primer.   But "high" is relative: if you're overpainting a chess board, that's going to take a lot of coats.  Paint and primer are translucent.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   Why are you lecturing me?  I didn't name the paint.

Answer (score 1):

You have two core problems.

A perfect paint match is functionally impossible.  The limiting factor is more the mixing than the scanning.  Mixing isn't precise enough.  Advice when doing a multi-gallon paint job is to mix all the gallons into a bucket, stir them together, then pour them back out into the gallon cans.  So buying another can, even with the same formula code, will probably not match well enough to get away with painting spots.

The second issue is texture or sheen.  Paints differ. When you brought in your sample, you didn't tell them whether it was a flat, matte, satin, gloss, etc. So you might not have gotten a match there. That will show.  Alternately, if you changed paint brands or grades, ones satin may not match the next's satin.

Answer (score 0):

It may improve if you stir it up.   The colorant dispensing machines are not super-accurate, and so a quart is generally less consistent than a gallon or a 5 gallon bucket.

Different paints also have different compositions, sheens, and hiding levels, so even if the color is right, putting a second identical coat of paint over a an earlier coat tends to create perceptions of light and dark.  Same with thicker or thinner coats of paint, or even with brushed touch-ups vs the original roller or spray application.   Paint also fades and gets dirty, so new applications rarely match exactly.

In general, I've been most successful by identifying the original manufacturer, year, and color, and asking the paint store to duplicate the formula rather than bringing in swatches and asking them to duplicate the color.